# Authorize only specific users for azure webapp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I own a private webapp on azure, i would like it to be accessible only for specific users, these users can login with any auth provider such as Google,Facebook of Azure AD.
**How can I make it a private application only for predefined users?**
currently the solution i picked:

- for my webapp set the Authentication / Authorization part to allow only authenticated users (all users)
- maintain a list of authorized users emails
- and for each request, i check the header `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME` and see if it is one of my "predefined users". if not, return `forbidden`

i guess the right path to go is the Azure AD and maybe assign roles

Answer (score 0):

You can use web.config file at the root directory of your site to restrict specific users. You may check the below example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="abc@Facebook.com, def@gmail.com"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also, you can add and edit the file using KUDU console (http://your-app-url.scm.azurewebsites.net).

If you want to use Azure AD for authentication, you can follow the below steps,
Azure Active Directory Settings blade you can select "Express Management Mode" and create a new AD Application to configure who will be able to access our web app. 
After you click on Save, try to access your web app through Incognito window (no session and cookies) and you will get redirected to the sign-in form.
To access your app, you need to sign in with an account that has been declared in Azure Active Directory App “NotPublicWebApp“.
To manage access permissions in your web app you need to click on Active Directory service that will redirect you to the old portal.
There you can add more Users to your Active Directory, while from the Application tab you can manage user access to your application.
For more information, you may refer this article: https://ppolyzos.com/2016/08/19/restrict-access-to-your-azure-websites-using-authenticationauthorization/.